# Why is there some extra space between my list item

Tags: css

[image]

[The HTML Page](http://jiewmeng.kodingen.com/demos/New%20folder/2011%20Archive%20-%20Jiew%20Meng%27s%20Development%20Blog.htm)

Comment: Who on earth is trying to close this?  It's a very valid question.

Comment: Sotiris has the right "fix" below, but you should really reconsider some of the CSS you're using there. It's convoluted, hence your problem here. You should really avoid the `*` selector for performance reasons, and sanity too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about if you remove the `right:5px` from `article.post footer.meta ul li.comments` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `<li class="comments">...</li>` you have `right:5px;` which you don't have on any other `<li>`, so it is probably that.

Answer (score 0):

Here might be the reason.

in your style-sheet around line **385**

you have the following selector:

```
article.post footer.meta ul li.comments{}
```

Try and remove the line that is stated:

```
right: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be an easy way to do it without modifiying anything else in your CSS.

```
li.categories{
margin-left:-10px;
}
```